# Fill Data On text Field json Value Like Show Profile

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, json

I want to fill data in a `UITextField` from the below JSON Value,

[image]

JSON:

```
{
    "username": "iC-1212121212",
    "first_name": "bla",
    "last_name": "rert",
    "email": "bal@gmail.com",
    "mobile_no": "1212121212",
    "address":
    {
        "addressid": "91",
        "addressname": "iC-1212121212",
        "address1": "hgfhfghfhfg",
        "address2": "",
        "city": "rtertert",
        "state": "KY",
        "zip": "424342"
    }
}
```

This value I am getting, I have to show in a textfield.

Comment: this is my response and i have to autofill from json response backend how

Comment: Store your json response to dictionary, fetch particular key value and store that value in respective UITextField.

Answer (score 1):

Change your code like this. Consider you getting this response in `jsonDic`

```
self.txtName.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",[jsonDic valueForKey:@"first_name"],[jsonDic valueForKey:@"last_name"]];
self.txtPhoneNum.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",[jsonDic valueForKey:@"mobile_no"]];
self.txtEmail.text = [jsonDic valueForKey:@"email"];
NSArray *addrArr = [jsonDic valueForKey:@"address"];
NSDictionary *addDic = [addrArr firstObject];
self.txtAddressLine1.text = [addDic valueForKey:@"address1"];
self.txtAddressLine2.text = [addDic valueForKey:@"address2"];
self.txtState.text = [addDic valueForKey:@"state"];
self.txtZipCode.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",[addDic valueForKey:@"zip"]];
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Hello Sir actually this value is giing null

Comment: Have you set your response in jsonDic?

Comment: yes i have sent i think the problem is creating issues are there is three view top view middle view i thing this is not creating

Comment: i add your Code on my code

Comment: I don't understand what you trying to say. Are you getting any error? If yes on which line.

Comment: i am not getting error but on text field data show null what is the problem also console data null

Comment: Have you set your response in the `jsonDic` i.e. `NSDictionary` ?

Comment: Are you getting value now?

Comment: no sir i am not getting value i sent u code

Comment: NSMutableDictionary *dict=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
 [dict setObject:dict2 forKey:@"address"];      after your code i am add NSMutable dictionary on my code please check it is right

Comment: Not here put whole code of your in question by editing it

Comment: actually showing some problem

Comment: can i sent via mail you

Answer (score 1):

```
{ 
   address = ( 
             { 
               address1 = aslfgh; 
               address2 = foggy; 
               addressid = 67; 
               addressname = home; 
               city = gushing; 
               state = Alaska; 
               zip = 12345; 
              } 
             ); 
   email = "bal@gmail.com"; 
   "first_name" = bla; 
   "last_name" = ""; 
   "mobile_no" = 1212121212; 
   plan = ""; 
   "plan_end" = ""; 
   "plan_start" = ""; 
   username = "iC-1212121212"; 
}
```

This is your json right?
This actually a dictionary.So store this response in a dictioanary say myDictionary.
I will simply write the code for your response.

```
nameTextfield.text= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", myDictionary[@"first_name"],myDictionary[@"last_name"]];
phonenumberTextfiled.text= myDictionary[@"mobile_no"];
phonenumberTextfiled.text= myDictionary[@"email"];
    address1Txtf.text= [[myDictionary[@"address"] objectAtIndex:0] valuForKey:@"address1"];
address2Txtf.text= [[myDictionary[@"address"] objectAtIndex:0] valuForKey:@"address2"];
stateTxtf.text = [[myDictionary[@"address"] objectAtIndex:0] valuForKey:@"state"];
zipcode.txtf = [[myDictionary[@"address"] objectAtIndex:0] valuForKey:@"zip"];
```

Thank you,
Happy coding;)

Answer (score 0):

```
{"address": [{
    "address1":"aslfgh",
    "address2":"foggy",
    "addressid":"67",
    "addressname":"home",
    "city":"gushing",
    "state":"Alaska",
    "zip":"12345"
}],
"email":"bal@gmail.com",
"first_name":"bla",
"last_name":"",
"mobile_no" : 1212121212,
"plan" : "",
"plan_end" : "",
"plan_start" : "",
"username" : "iC-1212121212"
}
```

Your JSON response has to be in above format, and use "Nirav Doctorwala" answer to display value in `UITextField`